# Difference between java 8u201 and 8u202

Tags: java

Can somebody explain what is difference between Java version 201 and version 202?
Java SE Development Kit  has that versions and Java SE Runtime Environment has the same.

My question is which of version should I download the latest one, 8u202or 8u201? Because I every time confused which version is better

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u202-relnotes-5209339.html

Comment: Because they both were released in January 15, 2019. Why Oracle didn`t release fixs in, fore example 8u201?

Comment: Oracle has been doing this for years: they release a version that only fixes security issues (and maybe critical bugs), and they release a version that may have other improvements, fixes or changes.

Comment: I came to Stackoverflow with exactly the same question, and I don't think it's off-topic. 

Anyway, for everybody who'll end up here looking for answer - Oracle's "Java CPU and PSU Releases Explained" article should explain everything:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/cpu-psu-explained-2331472.html